# Erro ao fazer Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Criei uma `View` aqui para logar em meu sistema, porém na parte de `ModelState.IsValid` só me retorna `false`, não sei o motivo, alguém poderia ajudar?

Meu código da `View` é o seguinte:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(Login usuario)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var loginViewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Login>, IEnumerable<LoginViewModel>>(_loginApp.GetAll());
            var validar = loginViewModel.Where(a => a.Usuario.Equals(usuario.Usuario) && a.Senha.Equals(usuario.Senha)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (validar != null)
            {
                Session["UsuarioId"] = validar.LoginId.ToString();
                Session["Usuario"] = validar.Usuario;
                return RedirectToAction("Logado");
            }
        }
        var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(usuario); 
}
```

Classe Login:

```
 public class Login
   {
     public int LoginId { get; set; }
     public string Nome { get; set; }
     public string Usuario { get; set; }
     public string Senha { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    }
```

View Login:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new { ReturnUrl =     ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
  {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

<div class="container">
    <div class="form-login">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">Login do Sistema</div>
            </div>

            <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body">
                <div style="display:none" id="result" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12">

                </div>

                <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Usuario, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "Usuario", autofocus = true } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Usuario, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Senha, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "Senha" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Senha, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">

                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                        <input type="submit" value="Acessar" class="btn primary btn-lg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  }
```

Comment: Coloque na sua pergunta a classe Login e a View Login!

Comment: Tem como colocar uma representação do objeto `usuario` na hora que é chamado o método `Login`?

Comment: está ai, a classe, e a view...

Comment: O que aparece em `errors`?

Comment: aparece System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManyIterator<System.Web.Mvc.ModelState,System.Web.Mvc.ModelError>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao utilizar a sua classe desta forma sem uma viewmodel, os campos como DataCadastro são obrigatórios não opcionais e o Isvalid retornará falso pois não foram recebidos pois não existem no seu formulário.Desta forma o campo é inválido, creio que o correto seja não submeter ao método IsValid e sim, testar apenas se o usuário ou senha foram recebidos via IF.
Exemplo:
if( usuario.Nome != "" && usuario.Senha != "" )
{
}